# Optimize calling a solution multiple times during a run

Tags: c#, optimization

During my current project, I'm calling a solution (which I'm going to refer to as solution2) every time the user presses a button (as long as the variables are correct). And I'm torn between calling a method inside solution2 on each correct user input, or to write everything in the start method and simply "activate" solution2 for each correct user input. I'm not too bothered which one is easier (except if one of them were going to cause major difficulty), I'm only looking for the most optimised way to do it. Thank you for your help. -TAG

Comment: What are the two types of projects for one? Big differences between say two winform apps, and a MVC project calling a project of libraries, or something calling a WCF app as "project 2". Also, why 2 projects at all? Is it relevent that there are 2 projects? Is that perhaps the actual problem?

Comment: I'm a studying game programmer, and I've been taught to rather use many solutions than one large, way more manageable on large projects. In this case, solution1 is a manager, which means it has to be its own solution (either that or spaghetti code). It manages a main mechanic while multiple other solutions make up how the mechanic is used. Thank you for understanding. -TAG

Comment: Hmm, A few things are getting mixed up here. There is a big difference between writing spaghetti code and writing multiple solutions. Is you primary concern organization and sticking to Single Responsibility / SOLID or more of an actual overhead performance question where using multiple projects isn't directly relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're torn between two different means to solve a problem, and optimization is your main concern, measure it! This is a good use of the Stopwatch class, but even just recording your current time and subtracting the time after function completion to get a diff will help you out. Make a (Release!) build for each solution, and run them each a large number of times to establish which one is faster on average.

Once you've determined the most performant solution, keep that one, and consider leaving the performance tracking in so that you can identify bottlenecks in your code. This will allow you to isolate and correct performance problems with confidence. Ideally you can separate your implementation details into their own class so you can refactor and optimize freely without needing to change the rest of your code.